# error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, gnu

i try install pcapy, but outgoing notifications like this :

> cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
>
> pcapdumper.cc:11:18: fatal error: pcap.h: No such file or directory
>
> #include
>
> ```
>      ^
> ```
>
> compilation terminated.
>       error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

i use ubuntu 14.04

Comment: You're most likely missing `libpcap-dev` package. If you specify which Ubuntu version you're running - I can tell you the exact package name.

Comment: Although it seems `libpcap-dev` is a transitional package, so installing it should give you the library that corresponds to you particular version of Ubuntu.

Comment: i use ubuntu 14.04 - @favoretti

Comment: Run `apt-get install libpcap-dev` and try compiling again.

Answer (score 8):

Installing the libraries, **libpcap-dev** & **libpq-dev** solved the problem.

> sudo apt-get install libpcap-dev libpq-dev

*Tested on Ubuntu 16.04.*

Answer (score 2):

i have the same problem ... on ubuntu 20.10. Basicaly the problema was... theres no python2.7 on this release ... i solved doing this steps...

> this part ll install general packages for python development tools on default python version... try if is solved ... if not...

`1 -` `sudo apt-get install python-dev`

> try install to especifically python version u r using...example if u r using python 3.6 then u ll type "`sudo apt-get install python3.6-dev -`y" ...

`2 -` `sudo apt-get install python3.x-dev -y`

> if instead not solve the problem try to remake the link on bin python directory doing like this...

```
3 - rm -rf /bin/python3 && ln -s /usr/bin/python3.x  /usr/bin/python3
4 - source ~/.bashrc
5 - sudo apt update -y && sudo apt upgrade -y && sudo apt dist-upgrade -y

sudo apt-get install libpcap-dev libpq-dev -y
```